# Stop computed to be updated in certain conditions

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is there a way with knockout to stop a computed to be updated when another element in the model view is updated?

Comment: why would you need this?

Comment: because this computed that is updated with the same value is going to trigger an html get to retrieve the same image

Comment: This work from Ryan Niemeyer should suit me: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/pausing-notifications-in-knockoutjs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a custom binding and check the new value.